# glb file not working in ar js version 1.0.4

Tags: javascript, git, web, 3d, ar.js

despite many attemprs, i cant find issue with this. Help would be appreciated!

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://google-ar.github.io/three.ar.js/dist/three.ar.js"></script>
<script src="https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
<body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
<a-scene embedded arjs>
    <a-entity gltf-model="url(CesiumMan.glb)" scale="0.2 0.2 0.2"></a-entity>
    <a-marker-camera preset='hiro'></a-marker-camera>
</a-scene>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively bring the glb in as an asset, which is the only way I've been able to get mine to work:

```
 <a-scene embedded arjs>
        <a-assets>
            <a-asset-item id="glb-asset" src="CesiumMan.glb"></a-asset-item>
        </a-assets>
        <a-marker-camera preset="hiro">
            <a-entity
                animation-mixer
                gltf-model="#glb-asset"
                scale="0.2 0.2 0.2">
            </a-entity>
         </a-marker-camera>
 </a-scene>
```

Also you don't need to load the three.ar.js library if you're using the a-frame version. You can simply use the aframe-ar.js and aframe.min.js to achieve the result you want